# How to access an Adapter that's attached to a Fragment from an Activity?

Tags: android, adapter

I have an activity with a view pager inside it. This viewpager contains 3 fragments. Each fragment loads images, hence, an adapter is needed.

I would like to know how I can access that adapter from my Activity?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here's what I've got thus far:

In my Activity onClick:

```
Collection<String> listURL = local_pics_fragment.getAdapterValues();
```

In my Fragment:

```
    static AdapterMultipleLocal adapter;
   ........
  public static Collection<String> getAdapterValues(){

    return adapter.hashmap.values();

}
```

But, I don't think this is good practice because it is susceptible to memory leaks with I'm apprehensive about.

Comment: You can use a Bus which can connect the adapter to your activity (vice versa) here is one of my favorite bus: http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Would this be better than using a static adapter? I've just set up my adapter so it's static. But, I've read to be careful about using static adapters etc, because they can cause memory leaks which I don't want to happen. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it would cause memory leak at some point(e.g screen rotation), having a bus would be as simple as passing data from one fragment to another no static reference will be use.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Would you be able to post an example of how I would be able to use it with with my Activity and my adapter that's setup in my Fragment?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I just updated my answer so you can see how I need to use it.